# Change Size of Header And Footer Invoice Template

Tags: templates, odoo, odoo-10

I need to change the template layout of the invoice of odoo system.
May i know what is the default header and footer height of the invoice template?
May i know which is the file that defines the height of the footer and the header and how can i change the footer to a bigger height?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the default header and footer template from the module named **report**
under the ODOO addons. From that, an external layout template is present which defines the template header and footer. So when you call an external layout in your own template, it automatically calls it's default header and footer. From that template id, you can be able to inherit the header and footer size. For example, verify stock module where the header has been inherited and changed to add the barcode.